# Deploy Rails + React app on Amazon EC2 blank page issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5

I have application with the combination of rails 5 + react.js. I am have deployed it on Amazon EC2 server. Application setup is done. There is no error till now.

Issue is **"Getting Blank Page"**. Contents are not being rendered on the screen.

Node modules are already installed on server.

Code from my **package.json** file

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "webpack": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch",
  "heroku-postbuild": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"
}
```

Tell me what's going wrong.